# Sort list with information from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, text-files

I have been reading class objects from a text file and stored the information in a list. My question is: How can I sort the list in a numerical order.

Text file:

```
Hugo 10
Isac 9
John 90
Kelly 8
```

Code:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self,name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def sort_list():  
    a = list()        
    file = open('my_textfile.txt', 'r').readlines()       
    for k in file:
        k = k.split(' ')
        af = A(k[0], k[1])
        a.append(af)       
    return a
```

Then I want to sort my list so that both columns get sorted numerically. Like this:

```
Kelly 8
Isac 9
Hugo 10
John 90
```

Comment: The list should consist of two columns and 4 rows

Comment: What is preventing you from even *attempting* to do this?

Comment: If you want to compare values as numbers, it helps to have numbers first (i.e., not simply strings that have digits in them). That said, sorting is built-in. Did you try putting e.g. `python sort by attribute` into a search engine?

Comment: "both columns get sorted numerically" – only one column is numeric. How do you want to sort *both* numerically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have found a solution now. If not, let me suggest something.

First, I made a slight modification to your class: I added a string representation that makes prints more readable:

```
class A:

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A('{self.name}', {self.age})"

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

You don't need that for the following!

Now the sorting:

```
def sort_list():
    lst = list()
    lines = open('my_textfile.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        lst.append(A(line[0], int(line[1])))
    lst.sort(key=lambda a: (a.age, a.name))
    return lst
```

Apart from renaming some variables I have made the following adjustments:

- I converted the second part of the strings to an `int` because I think that's what you actually want (`int(line[1])`).
- After appending all the data to the list it get's sorted. Lists have a `sort` method, but in your case you have to give it some hints on how to sort, since the elements are a new class. The hint is the lambda function given to the optional `key` argument of `sort`. It returns for every element of the list the tuple `(a.age, a.name)`. `sort` then actually sorts according to this values. Since the age is first, the sorting looks a it first and the result is an increasing age in the final list. For entries with same age the sorting proceeds in alphabetical order on the names.

The result of

```
lst = sort_list()
print(lst)
```

is

```
[A('Kelly', 8), A('Isac', 9), A('Hugo', 10), A('John', 90)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using the code you suggest.  Break the data into two parts sort it and put it back together again.   There are other ways of doing this with pandas.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
def sort_list():  
    a = list()        
    name = list()
    data = list()
    file = open('my_textfile.txt', 'r').readlines()       
    for k in file:
        k = k.split(' ')
        name.append(k[0])
        data.append(k[1])
    name.sort()
    data.sort()
    length = len(name)
    for i in range(length):
        af = A(name[i], data[i])
        a.append(af)
    return a
```

Comment: This does not appear to preserve the pairing between items. It will not produce the expected output.

Comment: Thank you! But I get: TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object